# Can I pause for console input in a SOAPUI groovy script?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I've got a groovy script in SoapUI that pokes at a web service - I want things to warm up for a few minutes before I attach a profiler, so I'd the script to run for the warmup period, then wait for me to press return after I've attached the profiler. Is there a way to ask for user input in the groovy script?

I tried something like this, but it always gets an IOException:

```
log.info "Press return when ready..."
System.in.withReader {
    answer = it.readLine() // java.io.IOException: Stream closed
}
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me propose you to pause on modal message box instead of console. Below is sample code with a message box that simply waits while you close it:

```
def alert = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
alert.showInfoMessage("Press return when ready...")
```

Comment: Never thought of a message box. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a most easy way to get user data!

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
ui.prompt("Write data u want","Data getter");
```

Answer (score 1):

just write "def" before aswer

```
System.in.withReader {
     def answer = it.readLine() // java.io.IOException: Stream closed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With java 6 and groovy, you can do

```
System.console().readLine "press return"
```

Whether this works in a soapui script is another matter... :-/

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't. System.console() returns a null. Using SoapUI 4.0.0 and Java 6.