# Soapui read soap response to dialog for user entry

Tags: soap, soapui

SoapUI.  I have a pretty old version of SoapUI (version 2.0.2)

We know in Soapui, we can present Alert, and input Dialogs..

Which work great..

I have the following SOAP Response and would like to read the question to present as a dialog.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="http://some.name.space.com">
            <ns1:payload>
                <ns1:Question>
                  <ns1:questionText>How much is that doggie in the window?</ns1:questionText>
                </ns1:Question>
            </ns1:payload>
    </ns1:Response>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to read or present the "questionText" to the tester..

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
ui.showInfoMessage("Hello World");
```

But, instead read the question (the questions do change) and to be something like:

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
ui.showInfoMessage("testStep.xmlResponse.questionText");
```

And then have where the tester can input their answer..

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
ui.prompt("Input Answer","Answer");
```

Thanks for the information at - [Can I pause for console input in a SOAPUI groovy script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567844/can-i-pause-for-console-input-in-a-soapui-groovy-script)

Here is what I have been able to find so far on this (which does not work at this point):

```
// pulled information from:
//  http://www.soapui.org/Developers-Corner/extending-soapui.html
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder;
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
def holder = new XmlHolder ( messageExchangeContentAsXml)
holder.namespaces["ns1"] = "http://some.name.space.com"
def node = holder.getDomName ("//ns1:Response[1]/ns1:payload[1]/ns1:Question[1]/ns1:questionText[1]")
ui.showInfoMessage(node.questionText);
```

The error that I am getting at this point is:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingPropertyExceptionNoStack: No such property: messageExchangeContentAsXml for class: Script12
```

And I think I should be able to "pass" that on to the next request fairly easily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out..

- http://www.soapui.org/Developers-Corner/extending-soapui.html
- http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html
- http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=2597

Reading from properties, we need the following:

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def propId = context.getProperty( "userName", "userName" );
ui.showInfoMessage( propId );
```

Reading from the Response in SOAPUI, we need to do the following:

```
def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("TestRequest#Response");
holder.namespaces["ns1"] = "http://some.namespace";
def responseId = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:userName");
ui.showInfoMessage( responseId );
```